# How to download bak file from url in .net core in iis?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have set the mime type in the **iis** `.bak=application/octet-stream`.
and the file is in the `wwwroot/backup` folder.
I find that a bin file `1.bin` is downloadable.

```
localhost/images/1.bin
```

but the bak file can not download `localhost/images/1.bak`
yes the `wwwroot/images` is the default static file folder.
how to add the backup folder?

I want to download file 1.bak in the url :`http://localhost/backup/1.bak`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using action to download file.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    

        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }

        [Route("/images/{filename}")]
        public FileResult Download(string filename)
        {
            string mimeType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(filename);
            string filepth = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "images", filename);

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepth, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return File(fileStream, mimeType, filename);
        }

    }
```

All tested and worked.

Test `https://localhost:44307/image/1.bak`

File download success.

To use MimeTypes, you need to install MimeTypes from Nugets.

[image]

Comment: This should solve the issue and would be especially useful if you want the requests to be authenticated (which you cant do with the static file middleware).
i would use  'return PhysicalFile(filepath,mimeType); ' to keep it a bit cleaner though but that may be personal preference

Comment: That's right and your solution also works. All roads lead to rome. It depends on the security level he need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide access to *.bak file regardless of their name or location (in wwwroot).

The easiest way to do this is to make sure that the DotNet runtime also knows the mime-type of the .bak files.  you can do this in the configuration of the UserStaticFiles() middleware as such:

```
        var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        provider.Mappings[".bak"] = "application/octet-stream";
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
             ContentTypeProvider = provider
        });
```

After that the .bak files should download just fine